# Want to know whether an 'UPSERT' operation performed INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: mysql, update, insert

I have a query where I try to insert a record and ready to update in case the record exists.

The question is that I would like to know, once the query is executed, if the operation has been an update or an insert.

Any idea?

Comment: I'd suggest you to change the title. PDO doesn't play a role, nor the fact that your statements are prepared. You actually want to "know whether an 'UPSERT' operation performed INSERT or UPDATE"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is **1** if the row is inserted as a new row, **2** if an existing row is updated, and **0** if an existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its current values.

So, if your statement would affect just *one* row, if the number of affected rows is **1**, then it is an `INSERT`; otherwise, an `UPDATE`. To retrieve the number of affected rows using PDO, use [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) method.